# How do you print C4 envelopes?

Tags: letters, envlab

What are the options for printing a C4-sized envelope in LaTeX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using `envlab` and `geometry`

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=324mm,paperwidth=229mm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{envlab}

\SetEnvelope{324mm}{229mm}
\setlength{\ToAddressTopMargin}{40mm} %Arbitrarily decided by me
\setlength{\ToAddressLeftMargin}{75mm} %Arbitrarily decided by me

\makelabels

\begin{document}
\startlabels
\mlabel{%
  %Sender
  Robert Adams\\
  3 Cardinal Drive\\
  Groton CT 06340}{%
  %Reciever
  Barbara Blais\\
  104 Thomaston Road\\  
  Preston CT 06365}
\end{document}
```

[image: Imgur]